# How can i achieve ListView PopupWindow in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Guidance required in achieving listView PopupWindow - Image Explanation

[image]

I'm a beginner in Android 
Please refer the Image. I get these data from the API Call. How could i bind a listview in PopUpWindow.
My Code

Window.Java

```
public class Window extends Service {
    public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            popupView, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

new HttpRequest().execute("URL");
}}


public class HttpRequest extends AsyncTask<String,Void, JSONArray> {

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        JSONArray response = new JSONArray();

        String responseString = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            responseString = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            response = new JSONArray(responseString);

            for(int Count= 0 ; Count < response.length(); Count++){
                JSONObject jsonObj = response.getJSONObject(Count);
                String TextHeading= jsonObj.getString("TextHeading");
                String TextValue= jsonObj.getString("TextValue");
//I get the data here
            }
} catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(urlConnection != null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@layout/customborder"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:background="#ffffff">
             <ListView
             android:layout_width="200dp"
             android:layout_height="200dp"
             android:layout_rowSpan="2"
             android:layout_columnSpan="1"
             android:id="@+id/list" />
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you want in alert dialog??

Comment: First just execute your API and store data in one Array list. On button click just open popup with listView and pass arraylist to custom adapter !

Comment: @Lakhan -  no as a popupwindow.

Comment: @PiyushGupta - I will Just try that now. If i use a TextView instead of ListView in popup.xml . The Popup opens and displays it. Where as the listView is not shown

Comment: Ok. That would be a good enough !

Comment: Yes Piyush is right. But why you are inflating xml  in Service? Use Asynctask to get data from api and update your UI in Activity or fragment.

Comment: I use this as service because its a Floating app with one button and popup that would be displayed Always on Top. Just like facebook Chathead.

Comment: How could i return the list back to the the Activity from the AsyncTask            String TextHeading= jsonObj.getString("TextHeading");
                String TextValue= jsonObj.getString("TextValue");
//I get the data here                                                                                             list.add(TextHeading);list.add(TextValue); return list

Comment: this is for you http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/04/alert-dialog-dialog-with-item-list.html

Comment: When i try to bind the ArrayList<String> to ListView i get error in ArrayAdapter.    lstVwText= (ListView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.list); ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.id.list, listCode);
            lstVwText.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);           I get red underline at (this,R.id.list,listCode)